# How to display Position number in this Breadcrum Schema JSON Generator

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Please have a look this is the code i am working with:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>FAQPage Schema Form</h1>
  <p>Add all your Questions and answers</p>
  <div class="border" v-for="(field, index) in itemListElement">
    <button class="removeBtn" @click="RemoveField(index)">
    X
  </button>
    <textarea v-model="field.name" placeholder="PAGE NAME"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea v-model="field.item" placeholder="URL"></textarea><br/>
    </div>
  <button class="addBtn" @click="AddField">
    Add a Question
  </button>

  <h2>JSON Output</h2>
  <p>After adding all your questions, add this code to your FAQ page</p>
  <textarea id="codeArea">
  &lt;script type="application/ld+json"&gt;
  {{$data | json }}
  &lt;/script&gt;
  </textarea>
  <div class="tooltip">
    <button class="copyCode" onclick="copyFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
<span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
Copy Code</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the script

```
function copyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("codeArea");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied code!";
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
//Begin Vue Code
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "FAQPage",
    mainEntity: []
  },
  created: function() {
    this.mainEntity.push({
      "@type": "Question",
      name: "",
      acceptedAnswer: { "@type": "Answer", text: "" }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    AddField: function() {
      this.mainEntity.push({
        "@type": "Question",
        name: "",
        acceptedAnswer: { "@type": "Answer", text: "" }
      });
    },
    RemoveField(index) {
      this.mainEntity.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it in action here:
https://codepen.io/adaprile/pen/orzxgr

Current output displayed is like this: (I have added where i want to display the index number of the Array Item.)

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
  {
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [
    {
      "@type": "Question",
       "position": "WANT TO DISPLAY INDEX NUMBER HERE",
      "name": "",
      "acceptedAnswer": {
        "@type": "Answer",
        "text": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
  </script>
```

What code can i use here to display the index of the array item as the Position number start with one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to add index of the array element to the element itself. So you can check array length whenever you push an element into the array:

```
this.mainEntity.push({
        "@type": "Question",
        name: "",
        position: this.mainEntity.length+1,
        acceptedAnswer: { "@type": "Answer", text: "" }
      });
```

Comment: "not working" Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry i messed up a variable, its working thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mythos hey mate i was wrong, he wanted to start from 2 :) cheers :)